# woocommerce плагин > виджет мини корзина

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Проблема такая, мне нужно редактировать виджет мини-корзины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел файл отвечающий за структуру того что в этой корзине, меняю его - 0 реакции...

Вот путь:

wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\cart\mini-cart.php

В файле mini-cart.php что - либо меняю, удаляю или вообще удаляю этот файл - на виджет корзины это никак не влияет..

Если кто то копал его, может подскажите где ?

Нужно саму структуру менять, по дефолту там все в ненумерованных списках, а мне нужно свои блоки написать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

скопируйте шаблон мини-корзины из
`wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\cart/mini-cart.php`
в папку
`yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php`
и меняйте ее как захочется